# Modal content not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

     <!-- Modal content -->
     <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close"></span>
               <h2 id="title-to-modal" style="text-align: center"></h2>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p id="description-modal">
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    <span class="text-center">  
                         <a id="ok-button" name="ok-button" class="next-button ok-button" style="display:inline-block;">OK</a> 
                    </span> 
                </div>
            </p>
         </div>

      </div>

</div>
```

I have the next code and I have no idea why when I have more lines the text is not going line by line...is everything on a line. What can I do to solve this problem? (The classes and ids don't have style to modify the content..just color..or border)

CSS:

```
#ok-button{background:transparent;
    border: 2px solid #202229;
    color: #202229;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;

}


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-title{color:#202229;text-align: center;}

#title-to-modal{margin-top: 10px !important;R}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #eeb821;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 25px 16px;}
.modal-body #description-modal{line-height: 20px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: is it Bootstrap? Where is your css? Post the css relevant to those lines

Comment: @mlegg yes! updated post

Comment: did you try to add height: auto; underneath the line width: 80%;